# How to read swagger file using python3

Tags: python-3.x, swagger

anyone please help me to find the way of reading `swagger.yaml` or `swagger.json` file using python. need to extract path, method, `url`, requests & response..

Comment: Are you searching for a Library *Recommendation* or *specific help* with a Library?

Comment: Check out the [prance](https://jfinkhaeuser.github.io/prance/) parser

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `PyYAML` for reading `swagger.yaml` files.
https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Install the PyYaml library with `pip install pyyaml`, and use it like so:

```py
import yaml
from yaml import Loader


with open("swagger.yaml") as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=Loader)
```

Here, `data` will contain a dictionary made out of your yaml file. Then, you can access whatever necessary from it.